# Display iteration count as a popup

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to display the current iteration of a long process as a popup window, instead of in the terminal. The count would need to update (or refresh) inside of that same one popup. As far as I know things like:

```
from easygui import msgbox
msgbox(iterationcount)
```

Don't update once the popup is initiated. It also halts the script until the popup is closed. Anyone have a novel solution?

Comment: You can probably take a look at the this: [progress_meter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress_meter).

Comment: @WoodBunny - make an answer out of it, with a quick demo, and you've got my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about msgbox, but if you're not set on using that, one way for updating a popup window during the iteration might be via matplotlib? I know it is a work around and not really an answer, but something like this should work (though can be improved with axis labels turned off etc.):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyp

pyp.ion() 
pyp.figure() #open the figure
pyp.ylim([0.9,1.1]); pyp.xlim([0.9,1.1]) #set the axis boundaries so the textlabel is central

for i in range(20):
   print "in iteration", i
   pyp.cla(); #this clears the figure so the text doesn't get overwritten 
   pyp.text( 1,1,"%7i" %i); #write the number
   pyp.draw()  #and redraw the image
```

I don't know about the performance of this - but if it's a long loop it might not matter so much.

Comment: Thanks. Unable to verify this because I'm running osx lion, which has known to be buggy with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

The pop up windows would never refresh automatically. The process is ideally paused until you close the window. To make this happen you would need to work on multithreads allowing one python thread to run the basic program and another to pop out the results in gui.

There are various ways to do this, what I am highlighting below is redirecting print ~ stdout.
All you need to do is to #1 define your program ---  in the following example its (myprogram) --- where I am redirecting "print input" to GUI.

```
def myprogram(input):
    input = 0
    while True:
        input = input+1
        print input

#Now, prepare your Tkinter window and a thread to execute it.

from Tkinter import *
import threading
import Queue # This is thread safe
import time

class Std_redirector():
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget

    def write(self,string):
        self.widget.write(string)

class ThreadSafeText(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        Text.__init__(self, master, **options)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.update_me()

    def write(self, line):
        self.queue.put(line)

    def update_me(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            line = self.queue.get_nowait()
            self.insert(END, line)
            self.see(END)
            self.update_idletasks()
        self.after(10, self.update_me)



root = Tk()
text = ThreadSafeText(root)
text.pack()
sys.stdout = Std_redirector(text)

#All you need to do now is pass your function to the thread below,

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=myprogram) # Where myprogram is the function we defined at the beginning
thread1.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions:-)